# $X$ is a random variable, $\alpha \in \Bbb R$ is constant, $Y=a-X$. Prove that: $R(X,Y)=-1$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$X$ is a random variable and $\alpha \in \Bbb R$ is constant.

$Y=a-X$.

$R(X,Y)=\,?  \,\,\,$ (The correlation)

My guess was that the answer is $-1$. Why? Because $X$ and $Y$ are correlated, according to $Y$'s definition. And since the coefficient of $X$ is $-1$, then $R(X,Y)=-1$.

I have no idea if that's the right explanation or why is that the right explanation. All i did was guessing. Plus, i have no idea how to calculate $R(X,Y)$ with no information about $X$'s distribution.

What is your explanation for this question?

Comment: Go back to the definition: $R(X,Y)=\mathrm{cov}(X,Y)/(\sigma_X\sigma_Y)$,

Comment: Apply definition. If you don't know the definition then it is not the time yet to ask questions about the correlation.

Comment: ok, that worked! I never applied this definition on variables which i don't know their distributions. I thought that if i don't have the actual value of $E(X)$ or $\sigma (X)$, then my result won't be a real number, like $-1$.
But, as it turned out:
$$
R(X,Y)=...=\frac{-\sigma ^2 (X)}{\sigma ^2 (X)}=-1
$$

Comment: But, just for the knowledge, my initial thought was correct?

Comment: Your guess was correct and your computation confirmed it.

Comment: Great:) thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As you have discovered yourself, the correlation in your case is $-1$.  But *not* because the "coefficient of $X$ is $-1$." If you compute the correlation between nondegenerate real-valued random variables $X$ and $Y=aX+b$ for $a,b\in\mathbb R,a\neq 0$, you will find

$$\text{Corr}(X,Y)\equiv\frac{\text{Cov}(X,Y)}{\sigma(X)\sigma(Y)}=\frac{a}{|a|}=\text{sgn}(a).$$

In other words, if $X$ and $Y$ are *linearly related* (regardless of the slope, so long as it's nonzero), their correlation will be $\pm 1.$ In fact, the converse holds true as well:  a correlation between $X$ and $Y$ of $\pm 1$ implies they are linearly related (almost surely), and you can find a proof [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160629/relationship-between-correlation-and-linear-dependency).

Since correlation is always between $-1$ and $1$ (by the [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality)), this exercise gives us the interpretation of correlation as a way to quantify the degree to which two random variables are *linearly* related, since the extreme case where correlation is $\pm 1$ occurs if and only if the pair is linearly related (almost surely).

In practical terms, changing the scale of a random variable (e.g. think about $X$ being temperature in $^\circ F$ and $Y$ being temperature in $^\circ C$) leaves it perfectly correlated with itself.

However, it is important to note the shortcomings of using correlation in isolation as a way to quantify dependence. In particular, $X$ and $Y$ can be nonlinearly related in many different ways and still have the same correlation. [Anscombe's quartet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe%27s_quartet) famously demonstrates this problem.

Comment: so.. wait a minute.. i must know: if $X$ and $Y$ are correlated (hence $cov(X,Y) \neq 0$), then $Y$ is from the form: $Y=aX+b  \,\,  (a,b \in \Bbb R , a \neq 0)$ .

Is that true?

Comment: No. If $Y$ and $X$ are *perfectly* correlated (i.e. correlation= $\pm 1$), then they are linearly related (with probability 1).

Comment: (The "with probability 1" part is just because they are random variables...they are technically allowed to do whatever the hell they want on zero probability regions)

Comment: They can be imperfectly correlated (i.e. $-1<$correlation$<1$), in which case they won't be linearly related in general. That is why correlation intuitively captures how *linearly related* random variables are.

Comment: Can you of two variables which are imperfectly correlated and show their definition? Just for example..

Comment: Here's an example of computing sample correlation, but you can take the sample as a population with each observation having equal probability weight of 1/n (where n=sample size): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=11c9cs6WpJU